# Open Weather Map does recognize city name when textField contains two substring

Tags: swift, openweathermap

if city name is "La Paz", Open Weather Map will not return JSON Data but it will return it if the user enter a city with one substring e.g. Richmond.

```
let urlString = "\(weatherURL)&q=\(cityName)"
```

how can I fix this? Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Can you provide more information about the failure? Like any HTTP log data you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you question is not fully clear, I assume the issue has to do with the spacing in the textfield. You could try it by using the function [addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1411946-addingpercentencoding). This will make the string more URL safe.

Otherwise I'd suggest checking the documentation for Weather Map and see if it requires data differently.

Answer (score 0):

An URL must not contain space characters.

To replace the space character with `%20` you have to encode the URL for example

```
let weatherBase = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather"
let weatherAPIKey = "••••••••••••••••••"
let city = "La Paz"

var urlComponents = URLComponents(string: weatherBase)!
let queryItems = [URLQueryItem(name: "q", value: city),
                  URLQueryItem(name: "appid", value: weatherAPIKey)]
urlComponents.queryItems = queryItems
if let weatherURL = urlComponents.url { ...
```

As you are going to include the API key and maybe even the `units` parameter `URLComponents/URLQueryItem` is a reasonable solution.